# How to resolve issues with IPv6 via PPPoE

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6, networkmanager, pppoe

I am facing issues that I cannot wrap my head around related to IPv6 and PPPoE connections.

I have a server connected to a Netgear router with WAN connected to ISP and server connected to LAN port. I am good in the IPv4 front and NAT working for my server.

The problem starts here... My ISP provides global IPv6 /64 address via PPPoE, and I want to host some service over IPv6.

**Scenario 1:**
I enabled IPv6 on my router via PPPoE and my router aquired a IPv6 address in the range 2XXX:YYYY:ZZZZ::1/64.Which I assume is called prefix-deligated IPv6 address (I guess). This address is reachable globally as I tried pinging the address from my network provided by other ISP.Also, my server gets a 2XXX:YYYY:ABCD:EFGH:JKLM/64 address. I am able to ping google IPv6 DNS 2001:4860:4860::8888 from my server. However, the server is not reachable from my other ISP network. why is that?

I also tried enabling port forwarding between external and internal ports on my router, expecting that requests comming in to my router's IPv6 address port would be mapped to my server. But it seeems only IPv4 ports are forwarded in my Netgear router and nothing on IPv6.

**Scenario 2:**
I change my router settings to IPv6 set to `pass-through` instead of PPPoE, assuming that I will do the PPPoE from my server directly to my ISP and get the global IPv6 2XXX:YYYY:ZZZZ::1/64 address on my server to make it globally accessible.

For this I connected my server via Wifi and cable to my router, and set IPv6 disabled on wifi and IPv4 disabled on my ethernet interfaces via Network Manager on Ubuntu 22.04.

Now when I enable IPv6 only on my ethernet by setting i`pv6.method=dhcp` and `ipv6.addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy`, I do get 2XXX:YYYY:ZZZZ::1/64 address. But this is of no use as I am neither able to ping google ipv6 dns nor ping my server from other network. Possibly because I have not done the PPPoE authentication (right?).

To resolve the above problem, I installed radvd and wide-dhcp6-client and created a PPPoE connection in Network Manager via the following command:

```
nmcli connection add type pppoe ifname eth0 username <isp-user-id> password <isp-password> ipv4.method disabled ipv6.method auto autoconnect yes
```

*I have enabled ipv6 in /etc/ppp/options as:*

```
+ipv6 ipv6cp-use-ipaddr
accept-remote
# MTU size not set, left default
```

*sysctl.conf:*

```
  net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

*radvd.conf:*

```
interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix ::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
    };
};
```

*/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c.conf:*

```
# Default dhpc6c configuration: it assumes the address is autoconfigured using
# router advertisements.

profile default
{
#  information-only;

  enable;
  pd;
  request domain-name-servers;
#  request domain-name;

  script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};
```

I have enabled and started the radvd service, loaded sysctl config too. I am not sure how wide-dhcp-client gets triggerred, I am not aware of how to make Network Manager to use the wide-dhcp6-client to aquire ip address.

After all this I am starting the new conection and it is successfully starting, but I don't see a ppp0 interface in ip a or ifconfig -a output.

I did see that /dev/ppp device is present and also manually loaded the pppoe kernel module before starting the connection.

I started the connection as:

```
nmcli connection up ppoe-eth0
```

I get the emssage: ppoe-eth0 connection successfully started. dbus....

I also see ppppd running in ps -Aef output with a bunch of options including my isp-user-id and isp-passwd. And I only see a link-local ip address on my eth0 interface fe80:abcd:efgh:xyz.

Can anyone suggest what is missing here and with a bit of explaination?

Answer (score 0):

For a general understanding: You have at least two IPv6 networks.
A WAN network (/64), you router has an address on that and a LAN network (/64). Your computers have an address in that net.
Is that currently the case?

There is no NAT, so no port forwarding needed.
Although, most routers have a firewall enabled.

For situation 1: If you can ping Google with IPv6 and get a reply, your connection is working.

EDIT: If you are still interested in situation 2, you have to learn about IPv6CP (that only negotiates a 64 bit interface identifier). That will be used for link-local addresses. Then a router-advertisement can be sent from your ISP and then either SLAAC or DHCPv6 can be used. If that has finished, the WAN interface is configured.
Then the LAN interface needs to be configured. This is were DHCP-PD is being used.